# What is the natural framework for Lagrangians in QFT?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics

I wonder what is the natural geometric setting for Lagrangians in QFT, in the case of a general polynomial $P(\phi_i)$ of fields which could be scalars, or spinors etc:

1. Are there natural, geometrical reasons that would limit the terms to certain powers of the fields $\phi^{n_{max}}$
2. Are there natural constraints along the lines of the TQFTs of Atiyah?
3. In the case of Lagrangians used in Feynman integrals, is there a good 'home' space for these?

I realise this is a general question however I am interested in research along the lines above.

Comment: Try [Deligne and Freed](https://publications.ias.edu/sites/default/files/79_ClassicalFieldTheory.pdf)

Comment: A Lagrangian is a(n in general non-linear) differential operator valued in volume forms of the underlying spacetime manifold. As such, there are no other structural limitations on what form it could take, whether you geometrize this definition or not. As it happens, there are some natural ideas for a geometric setting for Lagrangians and variational calculus in general, but I your question seems to be going in a (unclear to me) different direction. For some details, have a look at this [question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/349212) and also at various keywords that come up there.

Comment: As @IgorKhavkine says, at its most general a Lagrangian is a volume-form-valued differential operator. Within this setting, it is natural to look at restrictions on the operators. For example, it is natural to restrict just to elliptic operators, or just to hyperbolic operators. These restrictions improve your chances of defining a quantum theory through path integration. For example, I believe ellipticity is sufficient to have a well-defined perturbative Feynman-diagrammatic expansion.